# CMake with Android NDK: find_library() calls don't find anything

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm trying to setup a hello-world-like project using CMake and integrating the Android NDK. I have found promising documentation, especially on CMake's built-in Android NDK support.

However, there are a few problems that I am facing.

First of all, `find_library()` doesn't find anything. I am making a call `find_library(mediandk-lib mediandk)` to find the mediandk and save that to `mediandk-lib`, but when printing the content of the variable it only reports `mediandk-lib-NOTFOUND`.

Second, what's the best practice in terms of include paths? I understand that `find_library()` is not exactly `find_package()`. I'm not too sure about the differences, but if I remember correctly it does not automatically set an include path. So do I have to do that manually, pointing to the right folder withing the NDK installation, or how is that done nicely?

Here's what my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(playground)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK $ENV{ANDROID_NDK_HOME})
#export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Users/john/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION "clang")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE "c++_static")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI "arm64-v8a")

add_executable(playground
    src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(playground
    mediandk #I should instead use find_library and link against mediandk-lib
)
```

And this is my `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <media/NdkMediaCodec.h>

#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::cout << "playground\n";
    auto* codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType("audio/mpeg");
    AMediaCodec_delete(codec);
    std::cout << "done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So yeah:

- How do I make find_library() work correctly?
- How do I handle include directories?
- What's the best practice or gold standard in setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the test in the NDK that shows that this is working: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master-ndk:ndk/tests/build/cmake-find_library/CMakeLists.txt.

Use [the toolchain file](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake) and your problems will probably go away. We've tried working with cmake to make that unnecessary, but frankly it's been a constant source of bugs and afaict users don't benefit at all from avoiding the toolchain file.

FWIW, there's absolutely nothing wrong with just using `mediandk` like you have. `find_library` is overkill here.